# How to get camera origin from ModelViewProjection matrix? (DX11)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

How can I get the camera position from the ModelViewProjection matrix in direct3d 11? I've tried getting the inverse of the matrix and using _41, _42, and _43, but the location was not correct. Is it even possible?

Comment: The View matrix contains the information for the camera, you would need to decompose the 3 matrices (with the assumption that Model is identity anyway) and that would be non trivial.  Is there a reason for leveraging the matrix for this data?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a combined ModelViewProjection matrix then you likely have a number of elements combined so the camera isn't trivial to extract. You typically extract the camera position from the View matrix.

> You may want to look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for [DirectXMaht](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) which implements many common helpers. It uses row-major matrices with right-handed viewing coordinates which is what XNA Game Studio use

Comment: I'd even argue it's not possible to decompose the model-view-projection matrix in any meaningful way. It's like asking exactly what three values were multiplied to make the product 924.

Comment: It's actually not possible to decompose the 3 matrices.